# $object->($string)

Tags: php

I am dealing with an object of a class that I did not write and cannot change.This class has a very large number of attributes. I want to cycle trough about half of these attributes (a select group).  I put the names of the nescessary attributes into an array and would like to cycle through them.     Is this possible? What is the syntax like?

```
class B{
   public $foo = 'hi';
   public $bar = 'bye';
   ...etc, etc.
}

$arr = array(1=>'foo', 2=>'bar', ...)
$b = new B();
foreach($arr as $val){
  echo $b->($val); //<-----does not work
}
```

Comment: Remove the `()` as `$b->$val` or `$b->{$val}`

Comment: You need to use curly brackets `{$val}` instead of parentheses...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate through array and get key and value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753394/iterate-through-array-and-get-key-and-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
$b->$val; //Or...
$b->{$val};
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
<?php
class foo {
    var $bar = 'I am bar.';
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = 'bar';
$baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
echo $foo->$bar . "\n";
echo $foo->$baz[1] . "\n";
?>
```

> The above example will output:

```
I am bar.
I am bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $b->$val;
```

or method

```
echo $b->$val(params...);
```

and u can use one of the [reflection functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to get all the methods and members

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each variable like this:

```
$b= new B();

foreach($b as $var => $value) {
    echo "$var is $value\n";
}
```